# Linux on ACER Nitro 5 AN517 51 72CQ laptop

Tags: linux, acer

I never used Windows in my life. I am 60 years old with a PhD in computer science (coding since 1974, e.g. coding today https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon professionally), but not familiar with recent BIOSes (using Linux since 1993 and 0.99.12 kernel). I bought my [ACER Nitro5 AN517 51 72CQ](https://www.fnac.com/PC-Portable-Gaming-Acer-Nitro-5-AN517-51-72CQ-17-Intel-Core-i7-8-Go-RAM-512-Go-SSD-Noir/a13847678/w-4?Origin=SEA_GOOGLE_PLA_MICRO&esl-k=sem-google%7Cng%7Cc294697014403%7Cm%7Ckpla770084055483%7Cp%7Ct%7Cdc%7Ca58882736813%7Cg1558059562&gclid=CjwKCAiA66_xBRBhEiwAhrMuLQTQ93hQHbk_bIZfckS_hnH4T7XaNGu_qf7RYrqZqa6bFNH0o3sWARoC6GQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) for the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (a GPLv3 project for Linux x86-64) and I want to wipe out Windows entirely and have just Linux on my Acer Nitro5 laptop. I just successfully updated the BIOS to v1.23 using  Windows. The vendor who sold me that machine (and the Google checks I made) told me that it is Linux compatible.

The Ubuntu 19.10 ISO USB key is booting a Linux 5.3.0 ubuntu kernel, but I don't see any `/dev/sd?` device outside of `/dev/sda` which is the USB key. From `sudo -s` terminal, **the `fdisk -l` utility don't see any SDD disk.**
What did I do wrong? I did disable secure boot in the BIOS! Is there some kernel flag to set to boot a Linux seeing the SSD disk?

The CPU is according to `lscpu`

```
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
```

The label says that it has an NVIDIA GTX 1650.

```
 P/N:  NH.Q5CEF.014 & S/N: NHQ5CEF01494110EB3400
```

The output of `lspci`  is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a328 (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 25)
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
```

The secure boot is disabled in the BIOS.

The main issue is of course how to zero the internal SSD.

## solved with

The undocumented <kbd>Ctrl S</kbd> BIOS trick in the BIOS panel about disks enabled me to use [AHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) mode for the disk, and then it is seen from Linux

PS I did install a new SSD SATA disk and Ubuntu 19.10 runs on it. 
I did change the SSD M2 disk (the original one, WesternDigital with Windows) to a new Samsung 970 EVO Plus; the BIOS sees it, but not Ubuntu.

Comment: @GAD3R: why would you ask Basile to do that and not take advantage of UEFI + GPT ?  ... o_0  ?!??

Comment: Have you updated SSD drive's firmware in addition to UEFI update?  Are drive(s) set to AHCI? Many new systems use RAID/Intel RST. Drive may not be in sdX list, if NVMe type, shows firmware version also. `sudo nvme list` and `nvme --help`  You may need nomodeset until you install nVidia driver. And after install Acer requires you to set "trust" on Ubuntu UEFI boot entry.  Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118751/has-anyone-successfully-dual-booted-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-their-acer-predator-heli

Comment: Basile, turn off FastBoot or FastStartup (which has irreconcilable differences with Linux) in your BIOS menu; Maintain (i.e. do not disable UEFI); Boot from USB, and use GParted. If not included in the Ubuntu 19.10 ISO (I have a sudden doubt), do `# fdisk -l`  from terminal.  You should see all you want. Then wipe your SSD clean and repartition it to your liking. Then start fresh with your Ubuntu USB ISO with a clean slate.  I would recommend you to post on https://ubuntuforums.org or, as suggested by @oldfred, on askubuntu.com.

Comment: I have the Nitro 5 AN515-52-5336 and had no problem with Linux (Debian in my case) recognizing my drive (A mixed 1TB mechanichal 128GB SSD). I did have some problems since there was no legathy on the BIOS and I had to do the UEFI install, I also had some problems with the video card (mixed intel/nvidia) which solved with bumblebee (thouth I've seen there are better options with NvidiaXrun). Are you making a new installation of linux or are you booting from a live USB?

Comment: Everything is working thanks to that damned and undocumented CtrlS in BIOS trick. The BIOS of that laptop is a shame. It is written unprofessionally; the BIOS should show 'press CtrlS for more'